# keystore secured by hash

Tags: hash, keystore, keytool

I have test.jks file where password is test1.

I would like authorize by hashed password.

Right now authorization looks like: 
keytool test.jks -storepass test1

I want use password generated by md5pass. For example:
md5pass test1 xyz
$1$xyz$bqnG4BmfJcZTkNtM3IR74.

-storepass $1$xyz$bqnG4BmfJcZTkNtM3IR74

Comment: Well it doesn't work that way, the password formats are incompatible, regardless of what you want. You might be able to use the simple expedient of base64 encoding the output of md5pass, though I'm only guessing at what you're trying to do.

Comment: Here is example script:
https://gist.github.com/banterCZ/9bd6aa1ab49995fdf018

I see line :

 echo "Usage: $0 --keystore <keystore> --alias <alias>] [--password <password>] [--threshold <number of days until expiry>]"

I would like use in [--password md5($1$xyz$bqnG4BmfJcZTkNtM3IR74)]

Or other password hashed by sha, base64 or other hash